# ReBus Sql Server Consumer Polling Control

Tags: sql-server, polling, rebus

As I understand it, ReBus consumers poll the database for messages in two modes. Fast if messages are present and slower if none are available for a period of time.

Is there a way to adjust this, and is there somewhere that goes into more detail about how it works.

The only thing I've been able to find is this - "Added ability to configure queue polling backoff strategy to low-latency mode - thanks hagbarddenstore."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed correctly, Rebus backs off when there's periods of inactivity in order to not put too much unnecessary load on the queueing system.

The backoff strategy is configurable though, so you can do this (in Rebus versions <= 0.84.0)

```cs
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Behavior(b => b. SetLowLatencyBackoffBehavior())
    .(...)
```

in order to switch to "low latency mode".

EDIT: As @neo112 correctly pointed out, newer versions of Rebus (>= 0.90.0) use this API to modify the backoff times:

```cs
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o=> o.SetBackoffTimes(...))
    .(...)
```

If you're interested, you can see the timespans used for the default backoff behavior in RebusConfigurer.cs [where `DefaultBackoffStrategy` is registered](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Config/RebusConfigurer.cs#L230-L244).

Comment: Link nolonger works (https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Configuration/BackoffBehavior.cs)

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Rebus:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o=> o.SetBackoffTimes())
    .(...)
```